# Hierarchical clustering of different length time series data using scipy and DTW

Tags: python, scipy, hierarchical-clustering, dtw

I have a set of time series data having different lengths and I am trying to cluster them using Dynamic Time Warping (DTW).

For the completeness of the question, I am using [this](https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/alexminnaar/time-series-classification-and-clustering/blob/master/Time%20Series%20Classification%20and%20Clustering.ipynb) simple implementation of DTW

```
def DTWDistance(s1, s2):
    DTW={}

    for i in range(len(s1)):
        DTW[(i, -1)] = float('inf')
    for i in range(len(s2)):
        DTW[(-1, i)] = float('inf')
    DTW[(-1, -1)] = 0

    for i in range(len(s1)):
        for j in range(len(s2)):
            dist= (s1[i]-s2[j])**2
            DTW[(i, j)] = dist + min(DTW[(i-1, j)],DTW[(i, j-1)], DTW[(i-1, j-1)])

    return sqrt(DTW[len(s1)-1, len(s2)-1])
```

and I have my time series data of the form

```
timeseries = [[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
             [0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
             [6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14],
             [15, 14, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19]]
```

When I try

```
import scipy.cluster.hierarchy as hac

Z = hac.linkage(data, method='complete', metric= DTWDistance)
```

I get `ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.`, which is understandable because [`scipy.cluster.hierarchy.linkage`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.cluster.hierarchy.linkage.html#scipy-cluster-hierarchy-linkage) documentation says

> ...a collection of *m* observation vectors in *n* dimensions may be passed
>   as an *m* by *n* array. All elements of the condensed distance matrix must
>   be finite, i.e. no NaNs or infs.

And clearly my input doesn't fulfil this specification. What will be the correct approach to classify different length time series data?

**EDIT 1**

A simple workaround will be to fill the missing entries for shorter timeseries with 0, so that we can obtain an *m* x *n* matrix as required. I am not sure if this will alter the semantics of the timeseries.

Comment: You can indeed use DTW with series of different length, but your clustering function must also support that in the end. I don't know if [tslearn](https://github.com/rtavenar/tslearn) supports hierarchical clustering. If you can/want to use R, you could use my [dtwclust](https://cran.r-project.org/package=dtwclust) package. Otherwise, you could try linearly reinterpolating your series, see [this paper](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/216301292_Everything_you_know_about_dynamic_time_warping_is_wrong).

Comment: Yes, Alexis is right, see that paper ;-)  Eamonn Keogh